# What is so special about Taninim to be mentioned separately?

Tags: animals, parashat-bereishit, creation

> וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הַתַּנִּינִם הַגְּדֹלִים וְאֵת כָּל־נֶפֶשׁ הַחַיָּה הָרֹמֶשֶׂת אֲשֶׁר שָׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם לְמִינֵהֶם וְאֵת כָּל־עוֹף כָּנָף לְמִינֵהוּ וַיַּרְא אֱלֹהִים כִּי־טוֹב׃
>
> God created the great sea monsters, and all the living creatures of every kind that creep, which the waters brought forth in swarms, and all the winged birds of every kind. And God saw that this was good. ([Ber 1.21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.21?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en))

Why is the creation of Taninim (not sure what they are) worth special mentioning and not as a part of all sea and land animals?

Comment: If you knew what they were their significance would then become apparent - or what is the question please , I don’t follow

Comment: Unless you "go deep" on this, you won't get an answer. But Rashi in the 2nd part of his comment on the pasuk you cite points you in the correct direction. You ask why they get special mention and suggest they are not included as part of all sea and land animals. Why are you assuming they don't get included in one of those categories?

Comment: @YaacovDeane "And G-d created Yaacov and all humans" - what does it say about Yaacov?